# Jquery plotting multiple markers in google maps

Tags: jquery, google-maps

This is what till now

```
function xmlParser(xml) {

    $('#load').fadeOut();

    $(xml).find("da").each(function () {

        $(".main").append('<div class="data"><div class="name">Name ' + $(this).find("name").text() + '</div><div class="latitude">Latitude ' + $(this).find("lat").text() + '</div><div class="longitube">Longitude ' + $(this).find("lng").text() + '</div></div>');
        $(".data").fadeIn(1000);
        var lat = parseFloat($(this).find('lat').text());     
        var lng = parseFloat($(this).find('lng').text()); 
        //var lat=parseFloat(latt);

        //var lng=parseFloat(lngg);
        $("#map").goMap({ 
           markers: [{  

                latitude: lat , 
                longitude: lng , 
                html: { 
                    id: '.data', 
                    popup: true 
                }   

            },{
                latitude: lat , 
                longitude: lng , 
                html: { 
                    id: '.data', 
                    popup: true 
                } 
            }
            ]
        }); 

    });



}
```

the xml file is

```
<Data>
<da>
<id>1</id>
<name>vidyavihar</name>
<lat>54.9488</lat>
<lng>21.704</lng>
</da>
<da>
<id>2</id>
<name>atyty</name>
<lat>47.1234</lat>
<lng>10.1234</lng>
</da>
<da>
<id>3</id>
<name>uiuiu</name>
<lat>48.124</lat>
<lng>12.94</lng>
</da>
</Data>
```

I want to plot the markers based on the latitudes and longitudes provided in the xml file.
The function I have used is looping through exactly the way I want I am getting all the values properly in the div tags created. But I am not able to plot all those values on the map. Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new map for each entry in the XML.  Process through the entries in the XML pushing them onto an array, then create the map once.

```
     var markers = [];

     $(d).find("da").each(function () {

       var lat = parseFloat($(this).find('lat').text());     
       var lng = parseFloat($(this).find('lng').text()); 
       markers.push({latitude: lat,
                  longitude: lng,
                  html: { id: '.data',
                          popup: true
                  }});
     });

     $("#map").goMap({ 
       markers: markers
    });
```

[example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_jquery_multipleMarkersFromXmlA.html)